# App iOS stuck on blank white screen when build release React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode9.2

I'm setting up a new project using React Native like this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html and build iOS release but it does not work, the blank white screen showed after LaunchScreen run.

The app works if build in **Debug**(react-native run-ios) but does not work in **Release**(build release by Xcode or terminal).

react-native v0.53.0

react-native-cli v2.0.1

node v8.10.0

Xcode 9.2

[image: blank white screen]

The log show in Xcode:

> 2018-02-06 15:55:14.464233+0700 MyApp[306:35863] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
> 2561-02-06 15:55:14.697 [error][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:423] Failed to load bundle(file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/4FAF82CD-9EA4-4E73-800A-A2ABC9313405/MyApp.app/main.jsbundle) with error:(Error reading bundle /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4FAF82CD-9EA4-4E73-800A-A2ABC9313405/MyApp.app/main.jsbundle (null))
> 2018-02-06 15:55:14.706782+0700 Shiip[306:35863] Failed to load bundle(file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/4FAF82CD-9EA4-4E73-800A-A2ABC9313405/MyApp.app/main.jsbundle) with error:(Error reading bundle /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4FAF82CD-9EA4-4E73-800A-A2ABC9313405/MyApp.app/main.jsbundle (null))

Comment: I have the exact same issue. This needs a solution.

Comment: yes, I'm posted my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use many node version so the Xcode not using the node version which I used in my Terminal, it's make my app build crashed. Let's do this to solved my problem

Open The Script Build Phases in Xcode:
[image]

Now, using with the node version path exactly (use command: **which node** to get your node version path)

[image]

And my problem was solved

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How did you know it was a problem with Xcode not knowing what Node version to use?

Comment: I am getting this path when I write which node , I am using mac "/usr/local/bin/node"
Now my path becomes this 
export NODE_BINARY=/usr/local/bin/node../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
But when I do this my app gets crashed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

> Xcode v14.1
> React native 0.69.5

I found out that the error source is due to the node version which system use for running release build. credits to this answer [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366630/17541309)

I had to add the following lines in Xcode ==> Project ==> Build phases ==> Build react native code and images

```
export NODE_BINARY="/Users/<UserName>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0<Your_Version>/bin/node"
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

change UserName and Node version in this line accordingly

[image]

> If you need to test in release build before uploading to testflight
> for review

Go to Xcode ==> product ==> Scheme ==> edit scheme ==> Select Run ==> change build configuration to release
[image]

> to run a release build from terminal

you just only need to type the following command:

```
 npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release
```

If you want run your project on a real device use --device parameter:

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release --device "Your Device Name"
```

Answer (score -2):

The reason this is happening is because debug mode runs on the chrome javascript engine where as release mode runs on the device javascript engine. Some javascript features that work on chrome don’t work on the engines that mobile devices use. Please see mdn for more information there must be some js function you’re using that is undefined and causing the white screen.

Comment: If some javascript features not work in mode release, it will show error. But in my case, it's not show